# Better tool for managing git merge conflicts ssh and windows

Tags: php, linux, git, ssh, mergetool

Ok so my setup is we have 2-3 devs setup on github, my live server is on a digital ocean droplet (believe its a VPS) and i access it via putty SSH on my windows machine.

I have tried to use linux merge tool but i am sure there is better options out there. Is there a windows application out there that can connect via SSH and allow me to resolve conflicts in a GUI application. I don't mind if i have to pay for it as long as its not too expensive i.e $10-20 a month or under $200.

I have PHP Storm and was planning to use source tree for version control as that seems pretty good from what ive seen but i couldnt find anything to suggest either could do it. If that's not possible or easy i would settle for a good tutorial that would allow me to use mergetool better.

My big pain was i had some massive files and i just wanted to concentrate on the  parts, when i use '[c' hotkey it seems to bring me to every single change. There's probably a few more hotkeys that would make it much simpler but my real preference is for windows software that i can manage this in a GUI as its too easy to make a mistake in the cluncky editor.

Comment: You may have better luck communicating with each other on each other's changes.  Large conflicts are avoidable with regular pulls from the relevant branches.

Comment: What is "linux merge tool"? We use vimdiff for our setup and it works well. At home I merge locally and use tortoise merge. They are both setup to work pretty much the same other than vimdiff uses keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Hi user1547410. I'm in the same situation. Did you eventually find a viable solution? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any fully featured git client will allow you to do a merge between branches.

- [choose a git client](http://git-scm.com/download/gui/linux)

  - Source Tree is a fine choice.

### Get the branches to be merged

- pull both branches you need to merge together

  - after cloning make sure your feature branch is visible under "Branches"

    - if they are not listed click on "origin" under "Remotes"
      right click the branch you need
      then click "Checkout " + [insert branch name here] + " ..."

### Merge the branches

- select the branch that will have changed will be merged into.

  - double clicking on the name under "Branches" will do this for you.
- right click the branch with changes to be merged
- click "Merge " [insert branch name here] + " into current branch"
- a dialog will appear to confirm your action click ok.

### Dealing with conflicts

- because you have conflicts a new dialog will appear close this window and
- select the file status tab at the bottom of the interface.
- right click on the files that have conflicts
- go into the "Resolve conflicts" submenu
- choose any option.

  - I have several external editors installed so I clicked "Launch external merge tool"

### Selecting your external diff tool

- [Kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) is a fine choice
- [TortoiseGit] is a more complete git solution but much more than you need for this.
- click tools -> options
- click diff
- in section External Diff/Merge choose your poison

  - note: it will display every option even if it is not installed
    if it cannot find the executable in program files it will ask you on dialog exit.

Hope this helps.